# Why is this returning a #VALUE! error in Excel when I am using a simple LAMBDA function?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, valueerror, excel-lambda

I have attached a pic of what I am trying to do. The goal is to get `LAMBDA` to subtract the previous cell and then average that. (AVERAGE RATE OF CHANGE)

[image]

Comment: What is your excel version? LAMBDA() is only available Excel 365 latest release.

Comment: I can't reproduce the error, it runs fine on my setup. Might be worth mentioning that the average rate of change is just (last value - first value) / (number of values - 1) i.e. 1/24 for your data.

Comment: @TomSharpe This nugget of information is what I was looking for! Thanks